# How to provide a std::vector to match this parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, parameters

How can I pass a given `std::vector<float>` to a function to match the parameter type `float (*parameter)[3]`?

The function fills the parameter with coordinates of 3d points, that's the reason for the parameter type to be an array of 3-elements-long arrays. The function is provided by [a library](http://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/) and I cannot change it.

I already initialized vector to cover enough elements.

Comment: is it an option to change the header of the function?

Comment: What would be the problem passing the vector itself and then getting the needed elements inside the function?

Comment: The function is provided by a library which I cannot modify.

Comment: I dont think u can pass a vector to a function which expects some other parameter..

Comment: @Alien01. To pass a whole vector as array you can just write `&vector[0]` since it is guaranteed to be implemented as an array.

Comment: If you can fix the API, I recommend fixing the API. Taking a `float (*parameter)[3]` isn't a good idea.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the actual problem. Hope that there aren't misunderstandings anymore now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void f(float (*parameter)[3])
{
}

int main()
{
    vector<float> v(3);
    f(reinterpret_cast<float(*)[3]>(&v[0]));
}
```

Comment: This won't work... Shouldn't you be taking passing `&&v[0]`? `&v[0]` is a `float*`, but `parameter` is a pointer to an array of float.

Comment: I tried it and it works. C arrays give me headaches so I can't vouch for its safety.

Comment: I think a pointer to an array is still a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Doesn't this technicaly violate strict aliasing rules?

Comment: @Neil: Strictly speaking a pointer to an array isn't a pointer to its first element (just as the integer 1 isn't identical to the float 1.0 even though they're equal), but the array does have the same address as its first element so you're basically right, and that's why the `reinterpret_cast` works.

Comment: @jrok: I've never quite been able to satisfy myself from the standard that this doesn't violate strict aliasing, but if what the questioner wants to do is possible at all then this is the way to do it. Whether the contents of the vector are referred to via a `float*` or `float(*)[3]`, all access to the values of the objects in the arrays will eventually be via lvalues of type `float`, so there's a reasonable chance that it conforms to the standard...

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm guessing this bullet from 3.10/10 allows this: **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members**. Array is an aggregate and "aforementioned type" would be "dynamic type of the object" (first bullet in the same paragraph). So yeah, chances are this is legal.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's not just a question of strict aliasing.  Presumably, at some point within the function, the code will "access" a `float[3]`.  Which would violate the rule about accessing an object with a type other than the type of an object.  Or maybe not---the only "access" which is likely is an immediate array to pointer conversion, to finally access a `float`.  (The C standard was written to allow "fat" pointers and bounds checking.  I know that the opposite is illegal: accessing a `float[3][n]` as an array of `float`, but I'm not sure about this direction.)

Comment: @SteveJessop Of course, I can't in my wildest dreams imagine a system where it wouldn't work.

Comment: The wording is "An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array." If there is no such array, what is its first element?

Comment: @JamesKanze: exactly, because arrays don't have value semantics it is not in fact possible to "access" a whole array. So I think you can make an argument that the only access is to one individual `float` at a time. Like I say I've never been wholly convinced, but I think that argument might be right as far as aliasing goes. Then there's the issue, whether the pointer arithmetic involving `float[3]` is valid within an object that was never an array of `float[3]` in the first place. It probably isn't valid, but like you say it'll work in practice...

Comment: ... and I think it comes under the heading of, "things that the standard doesn't explicitly bless, but which if you could not do them it would be impossible to write a memory allocator in C++, and so clearly they do work".

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point about the memory allocator, but I do recall hearing about a "debugging" C++ compiler at one point, that did use fat pointers (except when calling into the system), and did full bounds checking.  I've never used it, however, and I don't know what it would do here.  (I can't remember what it was called, either, which makes googling for it a bit difficult.  And it would have been maybe 15 years ago.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I guess it depends how the fatness of the pointers works. If each pointer tracks the size (in bytes) of the array that it lives in then this code might conceivably work. If each pointer tracks the dynamic type of the object to which it points, then in principle the `reinterpret_cast` itself could notice that it is pointing to a `float` that is not part of any `float[3]`, and record a size of 0 or whatever.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's not clear to me either how the fatness would propagate through a `reinterpret_cast`.  The classical implementation of a fat pointer was with three raw pointers: begin, end and current.  But this is only effective as long as the compiler knows the types involved.  (I suppose you could add a fourth pointer, to the necessary type information.  But this starts becoming very complicated very fast, for probably little benefit.)

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no way to ascertain that an `std::allocator<T>` involves in some configuration a `float[3]`, it is not possible to point to such an array given an `std::vector<T>`. It is not a matter of finding the right cast, or the right value to cast.

The matter is that something like the function you described can only ever be passed a pointer to an actual `float[3]`, or a null pointer.

The only strictly conformant thing you can do is to copy the data to and from a bona-fide `float[3]` variable, passing a pointer to it to your function.

Comment: Btw, your sample code doesn't solve the problem, since the questioner's array is larger than 3 floats. The library function takes a pointer to the first element of an array of `float[3]`. But of course it gives the general idea and it's possible to write more elaborate code that copies from the vector in and out of a genuine array of `float[3]`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oops, I'd rather use words than code for this. Thanks.